# Custom review system with content type reviews and coasters

Tags: nodes, rating

I have a content type "reviews" with a node reference to "coaster". I want to be able to have users rate a roller coaster while writing a short review and giving a user rating. I added a Fivestar "rating" field in "review" . I would like users to submit review and rating, then on the coaster node display an average rating based on the individual reviews. So far I have managed to display the individual reviews on the relevant coaster node with a view and relationship and contextual filters. What is my best option to display the average? I've looked into views calc, but I'm relatively new to Drupal. Thanks for any help.